# Is there a convention for HTML tags to SO tags, or is it a bad practice?

Tags: discussion

I am asking a question about specific HTML5 tag (for example, `<output>`).
I tagged this question [html5](/questions/tagged/html5), but is there a tag that means `<output>`?

[output](/questions/tagged/output) does not really work well for that; it is too wide and abstract (not sure if it is useful for anything actually).

Is there a convention (like [html-output](/questions/tagged/html-output) or similar) that can be used?
Or is it a bad practice and something I should avoid? If so, why?

Comment: The annoying thing about this is that it's not necessary to use "tag" to mean two things here. You're really talking about HTML elements, not HTML tags (they have different meanings)...

Comment: And frankly, such a tag isn't necessary. It's an HTML5 question, 'nuff said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already tags like [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select), [html-lists](/questions/tagged/html-lists), [html-table](/questions/tagged/html-table), [html5-video](/questions/tagged/html5-video), [html-form](/questions/tagged/html-form), [html5-canvas](/questions/tagged/html5-canvas), and [html-attributes](/questions/tagged/html-attributes). Prefixing a tag name with html-, or html5- is already done, and it probably helps when the tag would otherwise too generic.

I cannot say anything about [html5-output](/questions/tagged/html5-output) being a useful tag, but [html5-output](/questions/tagged/html5-output) is preferable to [output](/questions/tagged/output).

Comment: Thanks, I tried some `html-` tags for some HTML tags before asking, but not for these ones. This pretty much answers the question for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have tag-tags like [div](/questions/tagged/div) and [span](/questions/tagged/span) and [iframe](/questions/tagged/iframe). Though the first two are probably unnecessary (and they seem to be used wherever there's a div/span in the code -- which isn't their purpose).

Such tags ought to be used when your issue is specifically with that HTML tag.

Tags are mainly for searching/filtering questions. I really don't think we *need* tag-tags for obscure HTML tags, they'll be pretty much useless. Nobody will want to look for questions on [div](/questions/tagged/div) or [blockquote](/questions/tagged/blockquote). We only need them for stuff like [iframe](/questions/tagged/iframe)s and [html5-canvas](/questions/tagged/html5-canvas)es, which have a whole lot of specific issues/rules (canvas has a whole section of JS/HTML devoted to it).

So it's better if we don't use such tag-tags unless, as mentioned, the tag is not obscure, and  "special", like `<iframe>`/`<canvas>` (with their own subset of tag-specific issues).

---

For ambiguous tag names (that aren't obviously HTML), use [html5-xxx](/questions/tagged/html5-xxx) or [html-xxx](/questions/tagged/html-xxx) (eg [html5-video](/questions/tagged/html5-video))